# Joomla, how to add custom field to the Virtuemart category form?

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

i am editing Joomla 2.5 site by coincidence. I am very noob in it. Can you tell me please what should i do to add custom field?

I has added new varchar field in 'virtuemart_categories_ru_ru' table of DB.

I has added new var in categories.php:

```
var $cat_h1 = '';
```

and

I has added this field in edit_categoryform.php like this:

```
<?php echo VmHTML::row('input','cat_h1','cat_h1',$this->category->cat_h1); ?>
```

But i can't get 'cat_h1' from DB with

> $this->category->cat_h1

and can't edit it from the CMS.

What should i do more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, there was something with cache. My task complete after uodate and cache clean.